# Prevent my Excel OfficeJS Add-In from disappearing from the Ribbon if it fails to load a required resource?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm running into a particular kind of failure for an internal Excel OfficeJS Add-In.

The failure is that if Excel fails to load an Add-In resource, the Add-In is removed from the Ribbon and cannot be used or re-added without restarting Excel.

This specifically happens if a user tries to use the Add-In while not connected to the VPN. Even after they've connected to the VPN and the Add-In resources are accessible, it's impossible to use the Add-In or restore it to the Ribbon without restarting Excel.

The ideal behavior would be that even if Excel failed to load a resource, the icon would remain in the Ribbon and it would make a fresh query for the resources every time the user tried to access it.

Is there a way to implement this behavior? Either within the Add-In manifest or within Excel or within our ActiveDirectory or Office 365 configuration? Or some other way?

Context dump below, erring on the side of too much context:

The Add-In manifest is centrally deployed to our organization through Office 365 Integrated Apps.

The application itself is a static single-pag
e React app hosted in a subdirectory on our own (Apache) webserver.

The webserver is only accessible on our internal VPN. We don't publish the DNS records.

The webserver's location is a subdomain of an internal subdomain of our organization's root domain, e.g.

`ourwebapp.subdomain-only-accessible-on-vpn.public-facing-website.tld`

but we only refer to it using the subdomain e.g.

`ourwebapp/add-in-subdirectory/index.html`

and rely on our centrally configured DNS Suffix Search List to resolve the DNS correctly (which works fine, and if we use the fully qualified domain name we run into separate, unrelated certificate issues).

The location is specified in the manifest with  `SourceLocation` .

When Excel starts up if the user isn't on the VPN the Add-In isn't able to resolve the address for the `SourceLocation` and  (obviously) isn't able to download the resources for the application. (Worth noting that it's an unresolvable domain, which I don't know whether that yields different behavior from, for example, a resolvable domain returning a 4xx error).

The icon for the application (along with all other static assets) is also hosted on the webserver.

I've tried moving the icon assets to a public URL but continued to see the same behavior.

The Add-In uses custom functions, which are also hosted on the webserver.

Excel displays an "Error installing add-ins" tooltip in the lower right that says "One or more add-ins failed to download a required resource."

Once this happens, the add-in icon disappears from the ribbon, as described above. Even going through `Add-Ins > Get Add-Ins > Admin Managed` and clicking Add on our Add-In's icon won't restore the icon to the ribbon or restore the features (even non-taskpane ones like custom functions).

If I restart Excel once I'm on the VPN the icon will (usually) reappear within the ribbon automatically, although we've had reports from some users that they have to go and re-Add it in the Admin Managed section of  Office Add-Ins dialog.

As I mentioned, the ideal behavior would be that even after an error downloading a resource, the icon wouldn't disappear and that it could gracefully recover. Is there any way to either implement this behavior, or otherwise change our approach so that this isn't such a pain for the users?

Is it possible to specify a fallback for the resources specified in the manifest and might something like that solve the problem?

[image: Error message]

Comment: When you moved the icons to a public URL, it was `https` correct? Though, to be honest, I think an Add-In will move forward if icon fails and just show the "blueboxes" icon. I can think of workarounds like basically, you'd have to host something publicly available and it would re-direct the app somehow to use the VPN when available, if not, it would display something like `are you connected to VPN?`

Comment: Just curious, do you use an Excel exiting ribbon or a custom ribbon group?

Comment: I think you're right @FreeSoftwareServers I've seen the "blueboxes" icon in the Ribbon if the icon doesn't load, so that's probably not the issue. (It was an https domain). I'm going to play around with hosting a public version of all the necessary resources that will fetch/redirect accordingly.if the user is on VPN. Great idea, thanks! Currently using the existing ribbon, do you think using a custom ribbon section might make a difference?

Comment: You can even manipulate the ribbon from an Add-In I believe. So you Manifest could point to a public service and then if VPN available, adjust the ribbon from the Add-In after loaded? Just a thought. Regarding ribbon positioning, it shouldn't, but you know how it goes, that doesn't mean it wouldn't have an effect possibly lol.

Comment: I have faced the similar problem of addin not loading without vpn, but after connecting to vpn and going to Addins => my Addins => Admin managed addins, there is a refresh button on top right corner, it tries to reload add-in. It reloads add-in successfully for me.